# how return a user avatar from database (SQL query)

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table `User_Table` in SQL Server 2008, there is a column `UserAvatar` (`varbinary`) that it can be `null`.

I need a query that returns the user avatar if it's not null and if it is `null` return the default user avatar that is saved in a specific row (there is a column named `ID` that is `PK`)

What should I do?

Comment: how does your record looks like?

Comment: @JW. there is  ID , UserName,UserPass,UserAvatar that UserAvatar May be NUll

Comment: and what is the default user avatar? is it another column? one more thing, how do you if it is a default avatar?

Comment: @JW. no it is a user that the ID=1 , UserName=default , pass = xxx and a basic avatar

Comment: i think you don't understand what i mean. hmmm can you give sample records with desired result along the question?

Comment: @JW. there are diffrent users in this table, the first user was added by me and i selected a UserAvatar for that user. other user may have UserAvatar or not! if they have UserAvatar i want to return their UserAvatar else i want return the first user that i added ( default ) UserAvatar data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_myDuplicateCheck
 @ID int,
@UserAvatar varbinary,
AS
BEGIN
SET @UserAvatar = Select UserAvatar from User_Table where ID=@ID
IF (@UserAvatar IS NULL)
Set @UserAvatar = Select UserAvatar from User_Table where ID=xxDefault
END
END
```

You can do the logic in SP and call the SP from Code and get the data.

Other Option is you can do same Logic on your code
Select UserAvatar from User_Table where ID=XX
by using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tckcces5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
IsDBNULL

```
if (dr["nameOfField"] == System.DBNull.Value) //Here Dr is your Data reader 
{
    nedID = 1;
}
```

Comment: my problem is that i need this query to use in my asp.net page  is it possible to do it without PROCEDURE ?

Comment: yes when you do that query you will read values using SQLDatareader and when you get the IsDBNULL(SQLDataReader["UserAvatar"]) and based on this you can select your defult image if condition is true

Comment: this error occurred ->> Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

Comment: will you have a Row for user for every ID and Image will be NULL?

Comment: Int32 ordinal = dataReader.GetOrdinal("ColumnName");

if (!dataReader.IsDBNull(ordinal))
    yourString = dataReader.GetString(ordinal);

Comment: sry but whats youString ?

Comment: That is just a variable ..if you get to know if its DBNULL or not you can again query for default image...instead of yourquery

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/stored-procedure-performance-using-%E2%80%9Csp_%E2%80%9D-prefix-%E2%80%93-myth-or-fact/). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
select case when u.UserAvatar  is null then (select * from User_Table uu where uu.ID = PK)
       else u.UserAvatar
from User_Table u
```

Comment: too general - and you forget the where !  - the select * in case of null Is not correct. You have a mistake, you send back more than one field.

Comment: The question never mentioned a where clause if needed they can add a where clause for filtration if they need it.

Comment: The query at minimum not compiled.

Comment: Do you believe that the null is the issue here ? a simple `select UserAvatar from TableName Where UserID=@UserID` do the work, but after that is the question about.

Comment: i think you forgot use END after adding END -- >
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.